# Gradle.properties with umlaut characters

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin, encoding

I write some text with umlauts to gradle.properties and declare resValue in gradle.build. After build application in file gradleResValues.xml in builds folder, this variable contains uncorrect symbols.

I've tried to set encoding in compileOptions in gradle.build, getting String(variable.getBytes(), "UTF-8), but it's doesn't work.

```
APP_NAME = Begrüßungstext // in gradle.properties

resValue "string", "appName", APP_NAME //in gradle.build

 <string name="appName" translatable="false">BegrÃ¼Ãungstext</string> // in gradleResValues.xml
```

Answer (score 2):

Use character codes, like `\u2321`.

In your case:

```
var appname = "Begr\u00fc\u00dfungstext"

fun main() {
    println(appname) // output -> `Begrüßungstext`
}
```

In gradle it will work the same way, as it's runs on JVM.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How I can replace symbols like this programmatically?

Comment: I don't know the way to do that. I use online tool, for example: http://www.mauvecloud.net/charsets/CharCodeFinder.html

Comment: Also, I am not sure if it would be a good approach. If you use unicode code then it's obvious what character should be there, regarding to regional settings, encoding etc.

Answer (score 1):

Try escaping characters with Unicode:

https://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/unicode-characters.html

```
ü -> \u00FC

ß -> \u00DF

Begrüßungstext -> Begr\u00FC\u00DFungstext
```